# How to get response page after auth in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get response page after form submit, but i have same page with empty form fields. I am trying use `time.sleep()`, but it dosen`t help.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

phantom_js_executable_path = './bin/phantomjs.exe'
user_agent = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.37 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2705.89 Safari/536.37"
)

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent

def main():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = phantom_js_executable_path) # or add to your PATH
    driver.get('http://any.syte.my/login')
    user_name = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    user_name.send_keys("user")
    password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    password.send_keys("pass")
    driver.find_element_by_name('continue').click()#form button submit
    #time.sleep(10)
    driver.save_screenshot('screen.png') # save a screenshot to disk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for an element in the page that you get after submitting user name and password.

```
ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
finally:
    ff.quit()
```

This is from http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Comment: `http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading` is it url that was allow to me after success auth?

Comment: That was just as example. You should use the part after 'try' block. So you will have to replace 'ff' with 'driver' and 'myDynamicElement' with the ID of element that appears in the page you get after successful auth.

Comment: I replase it, my code look like this:https://ghostbin.com/paste/qq9xz but it not working.

Comment: Are you getting any error? I hope you have imported these `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`

Comment: Yes, i have imported their.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will wait for an element to appear after your submit and will fail if the element is not located.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, elementFromNewPage))
driver.save_screenshot('weee.png')
```

Comment: That code dose not work for me, after form submir page was reload. Can developers detect that selenium using?